# jQuery with quicksearch plugin performance problems

Tags: jquery, plugins, quick-search

I'm using the [jQuery quicksearch plugin](http://plugins.jquery.com/search/node/quicksearch) to search for items in a table of data. Very slick and works fantastically well when there are a reasonable number of rows.

(Reasonable number: Less than 200 rows with 10 columns which an average of 20 characters per cell.)

When I increase the number of rows performance drops off and it becomes unusable.

I have 2 questions:

1. Are there any tips/tricks to improve performance of this plugin or something that I may have misconfigured to make it perform poorly?
2. What are the alternative jQuery plugins that I might consider to replace this one given that I anticipate having many rows in the table?

Answer (score 2):

If you have large number of rows, try approach listed on this page:

http://kobikobi.wordpress.com/2008/09/15/using-jquery-to-filter-table-rows/

Basically, you try to create an 'index' from the row data and while filtering, you only search this index and not the whole table.